# Add Outlook mail recipient with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I try to create an Outlook email from Excel using this code. The to address in variable strAddress is not added to mail. The recipients address stays empty. Whats wrong with this code?
I'm using the latest Excel and Outlook from M365.

```
Sub testmail()

   strAddress = "recipient@example.com"
   strSubject = "Testmail"
   mc_strEmailBody = "Testmail"

   Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

   ' Create the message.
   Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

   With objOutlookMsg
      ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
      Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(strAddress)
      objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

      ' Set the Subject and Body of the message.
      .Subject = strSubject
      .HTMLBody = mc_strEmailBody

      ' Resolve each Recipient's name.
      For Each objOutlookRecip In .Recipients
         objOutlookRecip.Resolve
         Debug.Print objOutlookRecip
      Next

      .Save
      .Send

   End With
   
   Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Outlook object library to your Excel VB project?

Comment: yes, the reference to the object library is set/selected

Comment: That works for me (using `.Display` in place of `.Save / .Send`).  Try adding `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and make sure all your variables are declared.

Comment: objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo is the problem. It works without this line or with objOutlookRecip.Type = 1

Comment: `olTo` works if you have added the outlook reference to your VBproject.  If you've not added that reference, then VBA sees it as an undeclared variable.  Likely your code also doesn't know what `olMailItem` but that constant has a value of zero so likely that's going to work "by accident"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a COM reference for the Outlook object model in VBA you will be able to use constants in the code. Otherwise, you have to declare Outlook related things as `Object` instead of using real classes and constants.

You need to add the `Microsoft Outlook XX.0 Object Library` entry in the list of COM references, see `Tools` > `References`. If it doesn't work, you need to remove the existing reference, restart Excel and add the entry anew.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer myself:

This doesn't work:

```
objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo
```

But this works:

```
objOutlookRecip.Type = 1
```

Or just without this line

Comment: If you add a COM reference for the Outlook object model in VBA you will be able to use constants in the code. Otherwise, you have to declare Outlook related things as `Object` instead of using real classes and constants.

Comment: `Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library` is selected in `Tools > References`. But when I do `Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application`I get `User-defined type not defined`

Comment: That is weird. Try to remove the reference and add it anew. Also re-installing Outlook/Office may help to refresh windows registry keys for the COM objects.

Comment: I removed the reference, closed and restartet Excel and added the reference again. Now it works.

Comment: Glad it helped! I've posted this as an answer.